# Qual é a diferença entre um arquivo .c e .cpp?

Tags: c, c++, estilo-de-codificação, extensão

C e C++ são duas linguagens diferentes, no entanto C++ é um "superset" ou superconjunto da linguagem C.

Então qual é a diferença entre um arquivo com a extensão em `.c` e `.cpp`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nada obriga ser, mas por convenção, até normalmente entendida por padrão por alguns compiladores, que `.c` seja arquivos de código da linguagem C e `.cpp` é para C++. Assim como muita gente usa `.h` para cabeçalho de C++, outros preferem `.hpp`. Há quem use `.cc` para C++ conforme comentário abaixo do Brumazzi DB, também por pura convenção.

Note que C++ é quase um *superset* de C, há algumas pequenas diferenças, principalmente se considerar C11. E mesmo assim muito do que funciona em C, recomenda-se não usar em C++.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só faltou falar dos arquivos `.cc`, também usados para c++.

Comment: É, tem quem use.

Answer (score -2):

A diferença é apenas por convenção mesmo. Alguns gostam de utilizar `.cpp` para diferenciar de um arquivo em Linguagem C.