# O que são os arquivos com extensão .cpp e .h?

Tags: c, c++, arquivo-header

O que são esses arquivos com extensões `.cpp` e `.h`? Como elas se interagem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

São arquivos com os códigos fontes da linguagem C++ [(`.cpp`) e C (`h`)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169142/101), embora tudo o que pode ser usado em C possa ser usado em C++ também e alguns programadores usam esta extensão mesmo em C++. Idealmente, para muitos, quando em C++ a extensão mais adequada é `.hpp`.

O `.h` ou `.hpp` conceitualmente são arquivos de cabeçalho e possuem códigos que o compilador precisa para compilar outras partes. Em geral ali contém apenas as estruturadas de dados (classes por exemplo) com as assinaturas de métodos e funções, além de implementações que devem ser linearizadas ou gabaritadas. Nada impede usar outras extensões para isto, mas este é o padrão.

O arquivo `.cpp` possuem as implementações, aquilo que depois de compilado não interessa mais para quem for usar o que está ali no fonte. Também é só uma convenção, poderia usar outra extensão.

Geralmente dentro do `.cpp` você "chama" o `.hpp` com uma diretiva de compilação [`#include`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45021/101) para que o compilador tenha acesso ao que foi definido neste cabeçalho. Pode haver `include` dentro de outros cabeçalhos também.

[Não que seja estritamente necessário fazer isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87883/101), só deve criar um cabeçalho quando o código deve ser usado genericamente em outras partes. É possível programar sem cabeçalhos, mas em aplicações complexas fica quase inviável sem abandonar o reuso de código.

Existe uma pequena [diferença no uso do `include`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175093/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Em algum momento, alguém quis usar fontes de implementação com extensão `.cc` ([mas isso na prática mal importa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1545080/4438007), é mais uma curiosidade)

Answer (score 7):

Arquivos `.cpp` são os arquivos que contém os fontes das implementações em C++. Arquivos `.h` são chamados de *headers*, usado para extrair a declaração de funções, classes e outras declarações da implementação, permitindo reuso.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969) eu falo sobre o processo de compilação de arquivos C. Em termos gerais, é muito semelhante ao do C++ por conter pré-processamento do arquivo fonte, geração de arquivos objeto e linkagem posterior.

Answer (score 1):

.cpp são códigos fontes C++ e .h são cabeçalhos de C (Embora podem ser usados em C++) C++ tem sua própria extensão de cabeçalhos .hpp

Answer (score 0):

Os arquivo .cpp é o fonte do seu código c++ e o .h são arquivos de header.

Quando você faz um include você esta adicionando uma biblioteca ao seu código:

```
#include "header.h"
```

Comment: Não são bibliotecas. Ambos são códigos fonte. Biblioteca é outra coisa.